# How can I retrieve a property with an ajax GET call inside a computed method?

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I have this view:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: dataSource">
    <tr data-bind="if: Enabled && DefaultSupplier.Enabled">
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: Id }, checked: $root.selectedIds" /></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Reference"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: DefaultSupplier ? DefaultSupplier.Name.Name : ''"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: CurrentStock"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The last property, `CurrentStock`, must be retrieved using an AJAX call.

```
//know how many articles in stock
this.CurrentStock = ko.computed(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/StockLines/GetArticleCurrentStock?ArticleId=" + { value: Id },
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the Id of the article, can be retrieved from the view like this

```
<td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
```

But I can't pass it to the ajax call as a parameter like this `{ value: Id }`. This does not work.

I would really appreciate some help because I'm new in the whole KNOCKOUT thing and I'm very excited about it and interested in learning how to use it for future projects.

Comment: Id is nothing within the context!
Assuming `this` is the viewModel within knockout, if you are sending the `Id` of the viewModel you should be sending it like `{value: this.Id()}`

Comment: The Firebug console throws this: TypeError: this.Id is not a function. :S

Comment: Mr... URL is a string. Why do you concatenate a JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did another approach that worked for me.

**View**

```
<h5>@ApplicationResources.Question_ShowOutOfStocks</h5><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: show" />

<!-- List of articles out of stock -->     
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: stocks, visible: show">
        <tr style="color: red">
            <td style="width: 3em">
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: id }, checked: $root.selectedIds" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: reference" style="width: 10%" ></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description" style="width: 35%" ></td>
            <td data-bind="text: supplier" ></td>
            <td data-bind="text: stock" ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**ViewModel**

```
// Array of articles out of stock
self.stocks = ko.observableArray([]);

// Boolean show 
self.show = ko.observable(true);

// Stock ViewModel
function Stock(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.reference = ko.observable(data.reference);
    this.description = ko.observable(data.description);
    this.supplier = ko.observable(data.supplier);
    this.stock = ko.observable(data.stock);
}

// Load data from server
$.getJSON("/Requests/GetOutOfStocks", function (allData) {
    var mappedTasks = $.map(allData, function (item) { return new Stock(item) });
    self.stocks(mappedTasks);
});
```

Hope this helps to someone else because it saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

Please use getJson. Now you can pass json object

```
$.getJSON( "/StockLines/GetArticleCurrentStock?ArticleId=", { value: Id } )
  .done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

Please let me know if you have any issues with this code

Comment: You can pass the object with `.ajax()` just as well (you'd have to use the `data` option), but `.getJSON()` is nicer overall.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I recommend you work with ajax in your observables ( fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jrhGg/1/):

html:

```
enter ID here: <input data-bind="value:ID"> <br />
click to talk to server:<button data-bind="click:send">send</button><br/>
status : <span data-bind="text:status"></span><br />
data from server: <span data-bind="text:dataFromServer"></span>
```

js:

```
var ajaxSimulation = function(dataToSend, callback){
    setTimeout(function(){
        callback("server says: you sent me: " + dataToSend);
    }, 2000);
}

var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.ID = ko.observable();
    self.status = ko.observable("idle");
    self.send = function(){
        self.status("waiting for response from server");
        ajaxSimulation(self.ID(), function(dataFromServer){
            self.dataFromServer(dataFromServer);
            self.status("response from server received");
        })
    }
    self.dataFromServer = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

You should always have a status box (or spinner), to convince the user that the app is still working while you are talking to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is well documented. Take a look at https://github.com/incredibleweb/knockout.async

When doing an asynchronous request, the computed observable will return before the AJAX request completes; hence causing it to fail. However there is a work-around.